# How to understand "no sooner let them play games in class than adopt Harry"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Professors McGonagall and Moody kept them working until the very last second of their classes too, and Snape, of course, would **no sooner let them play games in class than adopt Harry**.

I think "*no sooner let them play games in class than adopt Harry*" is a metaphor here. It's implying that Snape would never let them play games in class. It's because I understand Snape hates Harry very much from the book, so we can't really expect him to adopt Harry(I think 'adopt' here means "*take one into your own family and make one legally your son or daughter*"). In my opinion, it can be paraphrased as "*Snape would never let them play games in class just as he would never adopt Harry*". Is this understand correct?

Comment: Since it's an explicit comparison, it's a simile rather than a metaphor.  Your understanding of the meaning is correct.  The implication is that neither thing would ever occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. Basically, it means:

> He would adopt Harry before he let them play games in class.

*no sooner* is a little more subtle, because it could be "*before or at the same time*" instead of just before, but the idea is the same. The negation also kind of makes it stronger.